# Generate persistence mappings -> by hibernate mappings not available Intellij

Tags: java, hibernate, intellij-idea, persistence, mappings

I am brand new to Hibernate and I am trying have created the following class, which I now want to generate the hibernate mappings for.

```
package com.simpleprogrammer;

public class User {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int total;
    private int goal;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public int getGoal() {
        return goal;
    }
    public void setGoal(int goal) {
        this.goal = goal;
    }
    public int getTotal() {
        return total;
    }
    public void setTotal(int total) {
        this.total = total;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

When I right-click on Persistence I expect to see "Generate Persistence Mappings" -> "By Hibernate Mappings" to be available. But it is not. All I can see is "By database schema". Does anybody know why "By Hibernate Mappings is not available?

Will supply more information if requested or required, I am following a pluralsight course which is approx 2 years out of date and using Eclipse, just to make things even more complex!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add:

`@Entity` at start of class:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    private int id;
    ...
```

Then add `<mapping class="com.simpleprogrammer.User"/>` to `hibernate.cfg.xml` before closing of element `</session-factory>`

also med sure that you add ID annotation (`@Id`) to variable id.